# zsh: keep all command outputs on terminal screen

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to know how can I get `zsh` to behave like `bash` regarding this:
I want command outputs to always show up right below these commands in terminal.

For example, when I run the following command its results show up like this in `bash`:

```
john-doe@machine:~$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "USERID",
    "Account": "123456789",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/jonh-doe"
}
```

Whereas when executed in `zsh`, the results show up in a separate "editor" which I can quit upon seeing these results, but once I quit I also lose access to the command's output. There's a screenshot below:

[command output is lost once "editor" is quit (command execution was succesful)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7DP5.png)

I don't want to always have to pipe outputs to a file.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and `oh-my-zsh` with theme `powerlevel10k` (I tested other themes as well and `zsh` behaviour remains the same as I mentioned above). I also tested using `Terminator` and Ubuntu's default Terminal program.

Is there any setting to override this `zsh` behaviour?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried without _oh-my-zsh_? The simplest aproach would be to run `zsh -f` which virtually sources no config files. However, my guess is, that you set some environment variables inside your `~/.bashrc` which you don't have in your `~/.zshrc` (or vice versa) and these environment variables influence the behavior of the (to me unknown) `aws` command. Typical variables would be `PAGER`, `LESS`, `VISUAL`...

Comment: Thank you @mpy You are right about `oh-my-zsh`: the command I exemplified works just like `bash` when oh-my-zsh is disabled.

II'll inspect these `rc` files and try to find variables having similar names to the ones you've mentioned.

Answer (score 23):

The behavior you're seeing has nothing to do with `zsh` vs `bash`.  The behavior occurring because of how `oh-my-zsh` modifies the `zsh` shell environment.  In `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh`, you'll find these two lines:

```
env_default 'PAGER' 'less'
env_default 'LESS' '-R'
```

What `env_default` does is set an environment variable's value only if it hasn't already been set, so as its name implies, it defines the default value for a variable.  It also exports the variable when it sets it.  So if the variables `PAGER` and `LESS` have not yet been set to anything else, these lines are the equivalent of:

```
export PAGER='less'
export LESS='-R'
```

What these lines are doing is setting the default Linux pager to `less`.  This is what leads to the behavior you see that is annoying you.  If you run these two lines in a `bash` shell, it will start acting in this same way.

There are a number of ways to disable this behavior by setting the value of one of these two variables explicitly before the code gets to running these two lines of code.  A good place to do that is in  `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/config.zsh`.  One way is to set the `PAGER` env var to an empty string, like this:

```
export PAGER=""
```

Another thing you can do is configure the `less` tool to not exhibit this particular behavior unless the output in question is at least a full console window worth of output.  This would prevent the behavior in the case of your example.  You can do that with this line:

```
export LESS="-F -X -R"
```

The `-F` option is what does this.  I don't know why the `-X` option is needed as well, but it seems to be.

Finally, I'll point out that each particular Linux tool decides if it should use a pager or not.  If it does, it usually honors the `PAGER` variable when doing so.  The `ls` command, for example, doesn't use a pager at all.  No matter how much output it prints to the console, it won't exhibit paging behavior.  If a command uses a pager, you can often disable this behavior just for that tool with a tool-specific command. For example, to disable the pager just for `git`, you can do this:

```
 export GIT_PAGER=""
```

You can also disable the pager for a single `git` command. For example:

```
git --no-pager branch
```

will run `git branch` without running the output through the current pager.

I don't know if there's any way to configure if/how just the `aws` command utilizes a pager.  The other answer gives some options as to how to turn off paging for a single arbitrary command.  Here's another way, which disables the pager per the information given above:

```
PAGER="" aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue with the GitHub CLI and all of my `gh api` commands returning to a different screen. Adding `export PAGER=""` to my `.zshrc` fixed this.

Comment: awesome.  I'm always glad to help with stuff like this, having been on the other end of such issues many times in the past.  What DID we do before SO, lol?

Comment: @CryptoFool turns out it's also possible to disable AWS CLI's pager behaviour by exporting AWS_PAGER="". I added this line to my .zshrc file it worked like a charm. Your answer was really helpful for me to understand zsh settings and the overall pager behaviour. Thank you!!

Comment: I really appreciate answers like these that cover both the 'how' and the 'why'. for me personally, in order to invoke the pager only when contents overrun the window, I had to drop the '-X' and use 'export LESS="-F -R"'

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329811

Answer (score 0):

the quick fix is to just run it with bash.

```
bash -c "aws sts get-caller-identity"
```

or as said by [mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy), you should check your config file or use one of this command

```
aws sts get-caller-identity | cat
```

```
aws sts get-caller-identity | less
```

Comment: Thanks @MJBN. I tried all 3 suggestions and piping to `cat` temporarily solves my issue. Invoking the command from `bash` or piping to `less` both caused the same behaviour I mentioned in my question.